# How to get the last item of a split in Perl?

Tags: perl, split

```
$k="1.3.6.1.4.1.1588.2.1.1.1.6.2.1.37.32";
@a=  split('\.',$k);
print @a[-1];                           # WORKS!
print  (split '\.',$k)[-1];             # Fails: not proper syntax.`
```

I'd like to print the last element of a split without having to use an intermediary variable.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm using Perl 5.14.

Comment: You should turn on `use strict` and `use warnings`. It will tell you that `@a[-1]` should be `$a[-1]`.

Answer (score 22):

Perl is attributing the open parenthesis`(` to the print function. The syntax error comes from that the `print()` cannot be followed by `[-1]`. Even if there is whitespace between `print` and `()`. You need to prefix the parenthesis with a `+` sign to force list context if you do not want to add parens to your `print`.

```
print  +(split'\.', $k)[-1];
```

If you are not using your syntax as the parameter to something that expects to have parens, it will also work the way you tried.

```
my $foo = (split '\.', $k)[-1];
print $foo;
```

Comment: Actually I fall into that trap every time myself. :P

Comment: Or the most obvious solution, don't omit `print`'s parens when it causes problems! `print( (split'\.', $k)[-1] );`

Comment: The easiest solution is the hardest to think of @ikegami. :)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of creating a complete list and [slicing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) it to get the last element, you could use a regex capture:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $k = "1.3.6.1.4.1.1588.2.1.1.1.6.2.1.37.32";
my ($last) = $k =~ /(\d+)$/;
print $last;
```

Output:

```
32
```

Answer (score 1):

rindex() split last position while index() split from first position found

```
print substr( $k, rindex($k, '.')+1 );
```